# What syntax is this LESS variable @grid-breakpoints: xs 0, sm 576px, md 768px, lg 992px, xl 1200px;

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, less

In [bootstrap less port](https://github.com/seanCodes/bootstrap-less-port/blob/a97b1a85e49eaee50e20fe2505486d3808850c3a/less/_variables.less#L159) I see this syntax:

```
@grid-breakpoints:
    xs 0,
    sm 576px,
    md 768px,
    lg 992px,
    xl 1200px;
```

what is it? is it not map, not array...

How do I get value for `lg` for example?

What's totally weird is, that `map-get(@grid-breakpoints, lg)` works in angular 7 project in src/styles.less but it does not work in src/mycomponent/mycomponent.less. it is simply not translated.

Comment: *not array...* - it *is* actually. The Less port's `map-get` just supports interpreting this two-dimensional array as a map (so it is also a map in it). It was a [common method to create a map](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/ref.md#at) before Less v3.

Comment: *but it does not work in ...* - because you compile it w/o the bootstrap-port functions (i.e. `map-get`)?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: if you rephrase it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misread `less` as `sass` due to `map-get`... Still - your pasted code does not agree with the code in your link (you're missing colons). The code in your link is a straightforward example of [`less` maps](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature), and you should be able to use `@grid-breakpoints[lg]` to access `992px` (as long as your `less` is v3.5+). E.g.

```
@grid-breakpoints:
    xs 0,
    sm 576px,
    md 768px,
    lg 992px,
    xl 1200px;

body {
  width: @grid-breakpoints[lg];
}
```

generates

```
body {
  width: 992px;
}
```